# Property of Congruences on Inverse semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, congruence-relations

I'm studying Howie's Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory and during the characterization of congruences on inverse semigroups the following property is used a few times:

Let $S$ be an inverse semigroup. Let $\rho$ be a congruence on $S$. Then $(a,b) \in \rho$ $\Rightarrow$ $(a^{-1},b^{-1})\in \rho$.

I tried a few things, but I can't seem to prove this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the proof of Theorem 5.1.4 and formula (5.1.2) right after it? It fully answers your question.

Comment: Somehow I skipped that. Thanks